# How to upload larger files?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am trying to upload a file witch is 6.38 mb, but i did research and you can only upload 4 mb.

I was told to go change **maxRequestLength** in the  section in the web.config file.

But i cant fine  or **maxRequestLength** in my web.configs.

Could some one please tell me where i could find them using MVC or how to let larger files be uploaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you look for httpRuntime key as explained bellow?
http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2008/01/08/large-file-uploads-in-asp-net.aspx
AFAIK if the key is **NOT** present in your config file you can add it yourself.
You may have to adjust the timeout values too if you increase the allowed upload size.

P.S. 4MB or 6MB are **NOT** large uploads - I worked on the sites where the **average** uploads were measured in GBs, i.e. 5-10GB was **NOT** the largest.

Answer (score 1):

Its in configuration section of web.config file, if you don`t have httpRuntime element then add it, it would look like following:

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <httpRuntime 
      ...
      maxRequestLength = 'number'
      ... />
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Fore more info see this [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e1f13641%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) Article

Comment: I have 2 web.config files with MVC one in the shard folder and another just in the project witch one would i had to?

Comment: The one which reside in Root directory. (Not shared folder one)