# file upload error with mvc 3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm trying to implement simple [file upload](http://haacked.com/archive/2010/07/16/uploading-files-with-aspnetmvc.aspx). I've done the set up same as in the example given. But when I click submit with the file selected in the upload control, it can't postback to the action. The message I get is "connection to the server is lost.". If there is no file selected, it can postback to the action. I am using MVC 3, IE 9, VS 2010 and C#  and windows 7. I've tried in other browsers as well. I got the same message. I'm running everything locally. I'm using the development server, there is no IIS.
Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Where do you get this message? In developer tools? Fiddler? Or is it displayed on the page in the response?

Comment: when I click submit button I get this response. It is so strange. I did same thing in my work computer, it works fine. I've IE8 at work. Rest is same as mentioned above. Doesn't work at home machine. I downgraded from IE 10 to 9.

Comment: hi, I'd like to confirm that when you run in debug mode, the code never reaches the post back method, ( ie. it won't reach a breakpoint on the first line of ActionResult Index(HttpPostdFileBase ...))

Comment: no it doesn't reach the postback method

Comment: I'll reply tonight once I'm back on home machine

Comment: u can't upload a file more than 4MB.. developmet iis can't afford it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this in your web.config

```
 <System.Web>
     <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="value in kilobytes" /> 
 </System.Web>
```

You'll obviously have to change value in kilobytes to be the maximum file size you want

Comment: Anyway that was the problem. But there must be proper error message. Not just dumb saying You lost the connection. Thanks a lot @peter

Answer (score 1):

The issue is regarding the file size..

```
<location path="Home/UploadFiles">
<system.web>
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="40960"/>
</system.web>
```

Also take a look [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12401400/how-to-upload-larger-files)